# Is it possible to use select as an element in a jq list?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, select, jq, aws-cli

I'm trying to parse the instance id, state, launch time and name using jq from the following partial output:

```
{
  "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
  "ImageId": "ami-07c1483ef8c3dfece",
  "InstanceId": "i-0309XXXXXf6d500c",
  "InstanceType": "m5.2xlarge",
  "KeyName": "k8s-prod-ap-southeast-1",
  "LaunchTime": "2019-01-27T12:23:55+00:00",
  "Monitoring": {
    "State": "enabled"
  },
  "Placement": {
    "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast-1c",
    "GroupName": "",
    "Tenancy": "default"
  },
  "PrivateDnsName": "ip-X-X-X-X.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal",
  "PrivateIpAddress": "X.X.X.X",
  "ProductCodes": [],
  "PublicDnsName": "",
  "State": {
    "Code": 16,
    "Name": "running"
  },
  "SourceDestCheck": true,
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "Environment",
      "Value": "dev"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Project",
      "Value": "someproject"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "k8s-prod-ap-southeast-1-mongodb"
    },
    {
      "Key": "aws:autoscaling:groupName",
      "Value": "k8s-prod-ap-southeast-1-mongodb-moved-marmoset-20190127122348196400000006"
    },
    {
      "Key": "extra_tag1",
      "Value": "extra_value1"
    },
    {
      "Key": "extra_tag2",
      "Value": "extra_value2"
    }
  ],
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Without the instance name which is represented as a tag (.Tags[].Name), running this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance.group-id,Values=${group_id}" --profile ${profile} --region ${region} --output json | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | [ .InstanceId, .State.Name, .LaunchTime ] | @tsv'
```

yields the following output:

```
i-01eb8b857e00e61d6 running 2019-01-27T12:23:55+00:00
i-0b013248c2a238598 running 2019-01-27T12:23:55+00:00
i-03094d164ff6d500c running 2019-01-27T12:23:55+00:00
```

But when I try to display the instance name as well the command fails:

```
✗ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance.group-id,Values=${group_id}" --profile ${profile} --region ${region} --output json | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | [ .InstanceId, .State.Name, .LaunchTime, select(.Tags[].Key=="Name" | .Value) ] | @tsv'
jq: error (at <stdin>:448): Cannot index boolean with string "Value"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Your use of `select` is not quite right.  Instead, it seems you want:

```
[ .InstanceId, 
  .State.Name,
  .LaunchTime, 
  (.Tags[] | select(.Key=="Name").Value) ] 
| @tsv
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've edited my question to show you the output of your command.

Comment: Yes, I miswrote :-)  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no need to use `jq`** to extract values from AWS CLI output.

You can instead use `--query`, which follows [JMESPATH](https://jmespath.org/examples.html) syntax.

Here's an example:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,State.Name,LaunchTime,Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value|[0]]"
```

The output format can be specified by `--output`, such as `json`, `text`, `table` or (for AWS CLI v2) `yaml`.